# deploy .war file to Tomcat in Jenkins

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, war

In Jenkins, I build a .war file with ant1.8, and I want to deploy it to a Tomcat container, the settings as follows:
[settings of deploy war/ear to a container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAD48.png)

The deployment was successful. But when I checked the war file under tomcat webapps directory, the war file was renamed java.war
[war file name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQzzy.png)

There's a tip in the Context path setting of Deploy war/ear file to a container, it reminds "The context path that the container should use to publish the WAR/EAR. Note that this may get overridden if the WAR/EAR to deploy has container-specific configuration embedded inside." It seems some configuration of the .war file or Tomcat lead to this problem. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Is there a `context.xml` in the WAR file?

Comment: Yes, there is a contex.xml in the WAR file, and the context like this:<Context source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:java" reloadable="false" path="/java" docBase="java">

Comment: Thanks @Robby Cornelissen , i clear the path and docBase configuration, and it's ok now.